# Idomatic way to get Option value or else map into eitherT

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I have an option value passed into my method Foo

```
def Foo(barOpt: Option[Bar], barId: BarId): EitherT[Future, Error, Bar] = {

    for {
        bar <- barOpt.getOrElse(fetchBar(barId))
    } yield bar
}
```

Now bar is an Option[Bar], while fetchBar is an EitherT[Future, Error, Bar]. How can I either extract bar from the option or fetchBar if it doesn't exist idiomatically, as the types do not work out the way I have written the code above.

Comment: Is `Option(Bar)` a typo ? That's not a valid type. Did you mean `Option[Bar]` ? Want to make sure we have the exact code you are compiling

Comment: Yes that's a typo I meant Option[Bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps combination of `EitherT.fromOption` and `orElse` like so

```
def foo(barOpt: Option[Bar], barId: BarId): EitherT[Future, Error, Bar] =
  EitherT.fromOption[Future](barOpt, someError).orElse(fetchBar(barId))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be using `Option.fold`.

```
def foo(barOpt: Option[Bar]): EitherT[Future, Error, Bar] =
  barOpt.fold(ifEmpty = fetchBar(barId))(bar => EitherT.pure[Future, Error](bar))
```